# what is the shell script to read the log file and parse it, like get all the email adresses in the log file?

Tags: parsing, shell, logging

The log file contains many email addresses and i need to write a shell script to parse the log file and get all the email addresses. The log file's size is 1 GB, and my vps server's RAM is just 512m, so I want to take the performance into account. how can i do that?

Comment: Can you provide some example log lines?

Comment: the log file's content is in this format:wilby@gmail.com sent a file,whose size is 123k. and the next line of the log file is like the above

Answer (score 4):

if every line starts with email, you can use these coommands. First one select first 'word' of a file, and second gives unique values:

```
cut -f 1 -d ' ' LOGFILE.txt | sort -u
```